# translate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

Tags: python, google-translator-toolkit

I want to translate a tweet from Bahasa Indonesia to English, so after I can get a tweet, I run this code:

```
from googletrans import Translator

tweet = tweet.text # This saves the twitter text
tw_inggris = Translator.translate(tweet, src='id', dest='en')
```

But I got this specific error:

> TypeError: translate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

Does everyone know what's the error, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're using the `Translator` class directly instead of creating an instance first. Calling the `.translate()` function on the class directly would consider the first parameter as `self` and the second one as `text` (hence the error you got). So you'll need to do something like this:

```
from googletrans import Translator

tweet = tweet.text
translator = Translator()
tw_inggris = translator.translate(tweet, src='id', dest='en')
```

or for single use, you can simply do this:

```
Translator().translate(tweet.text, src='ar', dest='en')
```

Comment: I already tried it, but it keeps showing error as: raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Comment: @Berlian well that's a different issue then, but the way I mentioned is the correct way. now relating to your second error, what is the type of `tweet.text`? is it an `str`?

Comment: Oh I see, I just need to encode my tweet first. Thank you for your help.