# TypeError: Translator.translate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

Tags: python, translation, google-translation-api, googletrans

Im following this [tutorial](https://thepythoncode.com/article/translate-text-in-python) to translate text from spanish to english using python googletrans but i get this error:

TypeError: Translator.translate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

im using googletrans 3.0.0 and python 3.10.6

this is my code:

```
from googletrans import Translator, constants

translation = Translator.translate("Hola Mundo", dest="en")
print(f"{translation.origin} ({translation.src}) --> {translation.text} ({translation.dest})")
```

i already tried using `Translator.translate(text="Hola Mundo", dest="en")`

and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49355163/translate-missing-1-required-positional-argument-text) doesnt work for me, i get this error instead:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

i switched to googletrans==3.1.0a0 as said in this [tutorial](https://thepythoncode.com/article/translate-text-in-python) but the error persists

Any Help Would Be Appreciated.

Comment: The first answer linked says use Translator() with parenthesis. Your linked tutorials do the same

Comment: yeah, but it doesnt work using Translator()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you linked to is correct and the problem with your code is as described: you are calling the method from the class directly rather than creating an instance.

For future reference, in Python class names are typically written in title case without underscores (e.g. `Translator`, `DataFrame`) whereas variables such as class instances use lowercase with underscores (e.g. `translator`, `num_entries`). We more commonly (though not always) call class methods on instances of classes.

The correct code for this example is:

```
from googletrans import Translator, constants

translator = Translator()
translation = translator.translate("Hola Mundo", dest="en")
print(f"{translation.origin} ({translation.src}) --> {translation.text} ({translation.dest})")
```

Note that `translator` is an instance of the class `Translator`.

I also encountered `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` when running this code with `googletrans-3.0.0`, but it worked when I  ran `pip3 install googletrans==3.1.0a0`.

I suggest double checking your version of googletrans. If in doubt, run `pip list` to confirm the version you have installed before running the above code.

Output:

```
Hola Mundo (es) --> Hello World (en)
```